# I have added Magento product in WHMCS. It is not installing automatically after accepting order

Tags: magento, installation, whmcs

I have one prodct magento in whmcs and I am trying to auto install magento after accepting order but it is not happening. So can anyone help me for this.

Thanks in advance

I am not able to find any article or anything related to this